# Stop SSRS from Building ALL reports when Previewing

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to find some sort of setting in Visual Studio that controls whether it **Builds** all the report in the solution before letting the user **Preview** a report.

Currently, I am updating an old report. When I try to preview, the Visual Studio preview goes blank white for about 10 minutes then gives a bunch of errors about issues with different reports.

> The report preview failed because the report could not be built.

Unfortunately, Microsoft's MSDN is pretty much useless when searching for something (or anytime you want actual information and not theory). I've looked through every item in the Visual Studio menu but haven't found anything that sounds close to what I want.

It did not build all reports last week when I made changes to another report. I have other solutions which do not currently have the problem (it would make more sense if they did, tho). What setting did I change to make this stupid functionality?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - unfortunately, my VS now tries to build ALL reports in the solution then stops when it finds an issue in an old report. I tried restarting VS (and VSHub) but no luck. It worked last week.

Comment: even by just previewing the current report?

Comment: Yes - when I press Preview now, the screen goes white for about 10 minutes while it builds all of the reports in the solution. I'm not sure what I could have changed to do it - other solutions still work normally.

Comment: actually it's the correct behaviour... what you can do is create a project folder and chuck that one report so every time you preview it will only build the reports in that project folder in this case the only one.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend opening that report in Report Builder. It's a free download. You can use the 3.0 version or 2016. That way it will not be bogged down by the other reports, it has simpler error handling, and it has pretty much all the same editing capabilities. Once you're done making any changes, you can continue to manage it from within Visual Studio SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as an answer but too long for a comment.

If a report has not been successfully built previously, it will be built when you preview **any** report. Once the build completes, reports are skipped unless they have been changed since the last succesful build.

Usually when you preview a report, it builds just that report and skips the others.

You can prove this by going to a 'working' solution/project, right-clicking the solution and choosing `Clean Solution`. This will delete the build info for all the reports, next time you preview any report, **every** report will be rebuilt, you can see this in the `Output` window.
Once this is complete, preview any report and in the `Output` windows you will see `Skipping 'report name.rdl'. Item is up to date.`

I 'think' the status of each report is held in the project user options file (`*.rptpoj.user`) but I don't have anything that I can read the file sensibly with so I'm not 100% certain.

You may have to create new project and copy each report in one at a time fixing them as you go, I can't think of anything else, but hopefully somebody know more than me.

Comment: As I said, it was not an answer.... I tried to give the Op more info than I could fit in a comment. If you thought you had provided an answer, why not post it as one.?